# Handling file requests and availability

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file, jquery

I have seen file protection methods used in many web sites such as youtube , file hosting sites, music sites, facebook.. They are using special way to control the availability of the file....

Links look like this,

```
http://www.mysite.com/music/audio.mp3?Expires=1354180089&Key=APKAIKAIRXBA2H7FXITA
```

after the **expiry** , file is no longer available so the user who wants to use the file have to request it again with new expiry code... It will avoid illegal use of the file in other sites and it will protect bandwidth...

when using such a way, file is not available forever like in **http://www.mysite.com/music/audio.mp3**

I searched everywhere for tutorials but I couldn't find any.... Help me...

Comment: That looks like a lot like an Amazon S3 style link.

Comment: any tutorials to learn about creating these kind of style links?

Comment: Sure, check S3's developer guide regarding expiring links.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, audio.mp3 is not a real mp3 file, it is a script which checks the session expire time and if it is valid, makes the right header, and prints out the real mp3 file which is located somewhere on the server and only the script can access it. something like this pseudo code:

```
  if (session valid) {
       //set the right header;
       //print out the mp3 file;
  } else {
       //text/html header;
       //print the message about session being invalid;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but if the session is valid, it will produce  real location of the file so if someone got that he could use it instead of protected link?? so I have to copy the file every time it generates a session and at the end of the session I have to delete it also... but what if 100 users requested same 10mb file at once, I will be out of web server space..

Comment: you're not copying the file every time, your printing it or sending it to the user as a stream. basically you read the mp3 file content and print it with the right header